# Letters having the same equivalence

Tags: java

Looking ideas on how to go about accomplishing this. Basically I want certain characters to have equivalence.

For example: M = N

So: Mum = Nun

However: Mum can also equal Num.

I was advised to try a map of replacements and this worked until the third example where not all M's are to be changed to N's.

Thanks

This is the code for the map of replacements:

```
HashMap<String,String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
                replacements.put("n","m");
                replacements.put("m","n");

                String ignoreFirstChar = names[j].charAt(0) + (names[j].substring(1,names[j].length()).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "").toLowerCase());

                String result = "";
                for(int i1 = 0; i1 < ignoreFirstChar.length(); i1++) {
                    String rpl = replacements.get(ignoreFirstChar.charAt(i1)+"");
                    result += rpl==null?ignoreFirstChar.charAt(i1):rpl;
                }


                System.out.println(ignoreFirstChar);
                System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried? It's tough to tell what you're actually asking here.

Comment: Maybe another approach would be to use equivalence classes: replace all instances of values inside one class with an distinct symbol (maybe `#`) and then compare the resulting strings. Check this for every equivalence class separately.

Comment: I'd probably just assign them numeric values and them add them up. Maybe like A = 1, B = 2, C = 4, D = 8 etc, but then I'm not sure what you mean by "not all M's are to be changed to N's". If you are checking for string equivalence, then does it matter whether an M is an N or not if M = N?

Comment: We need more clarity on why sometimes Ms are not Ns.

Comment: @MikeB I added the code I have at the moment. This just replaces N with M and vice versa. However during the testing I realised that there are scenarios where the characters arent changed. Not sure if i am exaplining it well.

Comment: Well, "M" is not the same as "m" so it wouldn't change the uppercase M's to "n" automatically.

Comment: @MxyL Sorry did not mean to put upper case in the comment. replacing dosent work in instances such as when num is equal to mum. I am looking a way to basically go trough each character of two strings. Say character one of string one is m, and character one of string two is n, then it equates that these are equal.

Comment: The idea of "replacing" characters is to normalize the strings. Let's say you were given the string "num". If `m = n`, then it really doesn't matter whether you have an `n` or an `m` in your string. So you normalize your string by replacing all `n`'s with `m`'s, and then compare the two strings. `num` would be normalized to `mum` because `n = m`, and therefore you can easily check that they (`num` and `mum`) are equivalent by comparing the normalized forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume M and m are not equivalent. Therefore, if M = N, we cannot say M = n.  If you would like to use a "map of replacements" as you have been suggested, I would use it for the purpose of normalizing your strings.

You would take the current problem of

```
Given strings x and y, determine whether x equals y
```

and change it to

```
Given strings x and y, determine whether normalize(x) equals normalize(y)
```

The purpose of normalizing your strings is to apply any equivalence rules that you have, such as M = N. That way "Mum" would be converted to "Num", and then you can compare the two strings without having to worry about the rules because they've already been applied.

The `normalize` method would look something like

```
/* 
 * Takes each character in inStr and replaces them as necessary based on
 * your replacement map. For example, if you see an "n", then replace it with "m"
 */
String normalize(String inStr) {
   String newStr;

   // something happens

   return newStr;
}
```

If case-sensitivity is not important, then you would again normalize your strings by first converting them to lower-case or upper-case (doesn't matter, as long as it is consistent)

Comment: Thank you, I tried your first suggestion of giving each letter a numeric value. I thought this would be better for instances where numerous letters have the same equivalence. Not sure if the above example would allow that. You have been a big help. Thank you.

Comment: @NatalieCarr Be careful with the value assignments. For example, I've seen some implementations assign `A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, ... ` and then it was telling me `c` was equivalent to `ab`.

Comment: Yeah, starting to see little bugs. Would you have any other suggestions? E.g. as well as M and N being equal. All vowels are also equivalent and I am not sure the normalisation above would work for this.

Comment: @NatalieCarr If you assume all vowels are equal, then you would just convert them all to a particular vowel. If you assume 10 arbitrary letters are all equal, then you would just pick one of them and make sure everything else converts to that one.

Comment: If you want to use numbers, you can just assign binary values. A = 1, B = 2, C = 4, D = 8, etc. Then you are guaranteed that there are no two unique combination of letters that add up to the same values.

Comment: Thank you, I changed to your last recommendation and so far so good. Will conduct more testing. Thank you so much :)